# Transform with group by in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am creating a Dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

 df1 = pd.DataFrame( {     
"Name" : ["Alice", "Bob", "Mallory", "Mallory", "Bob" , "Mallory"] ,           
"City" : ["Seattle", "Seattle", "Portland", "Seattle", "Seattle",     
"Portland"]   } )          

df1.groupby( ["City"] )['Name'].transform(lambda x:     
','.join(x)).drop_duplicates()      
I want the output as      

Name    City                 
Alice,Bob,Mallory,Bob     Seattle           
Mallory,Mallory    Portland        

but i am getting only           
Name         
Alice,Bob,Mallory,Bob                
Mallory,Mallory        

This is an example with small number of columns but in my actual problem i 
have too many columns so i cannot use           
df1['Name']= df1.groupby( ['City'] )['Name'].transform(lambda x:         
','.join(x))              
df1.groupby( ['City','Name'], as_index=False )              
df1.drop_duplicates()
```

because for each column i have to write the same code
Is there any way to do it without writing transform for each column 
individually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. column aggregation**

I think you need [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with `,.join`, then for change order use double `[[]]`:

```
df = df1.groupby(["City"])['Name'].apply(','.join).reset_index()
df = df[['Name','City']]
print (df)
                    Name      City
0        Mallory,Mallory  Portland
1  Alice,Bob,Mallory,Bob   Seattle
```

Because [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) create new column with aggregate values:

```
df1['new'] = df1.groupby("City")['Name'].transform(','.join)
print (df1)
       City     Name                    new
0   Seattle    Alice  Alice,Bob,Mallory,Bob
1   Seattle      Bob  Alice,Bob,Mallory,Bob
2  Portland  Mallory        Mallory,Mallory
3   Seattle  Mallory  Alice,Bob,Mallory,Bob
4   Seattle      Bob  Alice,Bob,Mallory,Bob
5  Portland  Mallory        Mallory,Mallory
```

**2. columns and more aggregation**

If more columns need [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with specify columns in `[]` or no specifying for join all string columns:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame( {     
"Name" : ["Alice", "Bob", "Mallory", "Mallory", "Bob" , "Mallory"] ,  
"Name2":   ["Alice1", "Bob1", "Mallory1", "Mallory1", "Bob1" , "Mallory1"],      
"City" : ["Seattle", "Seattle", "Portland", "Seattle", "Seattle",     
"Portland"]   } )   
print (df1)
       City     Name     Name2
0   Seattle    Alice    Alice1
1   Seattle      Bob      Bob1
2  Portland  Mallory  Mallory1
3   Seattle  Mallory  Mallory1
4   Seattle      Bob      Bob1
5  Portland  Mallory  Mallory1

df = df = df1.groupby('City')['Name', 'Name2'].agg(','.join).reset_index()
print (df)
       City                   Name                      Name2
0  Portland        Mallory,Mallory          Mallory1,Mallory1
1   Seattle  Alice,Bob,Mallory,Bob  Alice1,Bob1,Mallory1,Bob1
```

Anf if need aggregate all columns:

```
df = df1.groupby('City').agg(','.join).reset_index()
print (df)
       City                   Name                      Name2
0  Portland        Mallory,Mallory          Mallory1,Mallory1
1   Seattle  Alice,Bob,Mallory,Bob  Alice1,Bob1,Mallory1,Bob1
```

---

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame( {     
"Name" : ["Alice", "Bob", "Mallory", "Mallory", "Bob" , "Mallory"] ,  
"Name2":   ["Alice1", "Bob1", "Mallory1", "Mallory1", "Bob1" , "Mallory1"],      
"City" : ["Seattle", "Seattle", "Portland", "Seattle", "Seattle", "Portland"],
'Numbers':[1,5,4,3,2,1]} )   
print (df1)
       City     Name     Name2  Numbers
0   Seattle    Alice    Alice1        1
1   Seattle      Bob      Bob1        5
2  Portland  Mallory  Mallory1        4
3   Seattle  Mallory  Mallory1        3
4   Seattle      Bob      Bob1        2
5  Portland  Mallory  Mallory1        1


df = df1.groupby('City').agg({'Name': ','.join, 
                              'Name2': ','.join, 
                              'Numbers': 'max'}).reset_index()
print (df)
       City                   Name                      Name2  Numbers
0  Portland        Mallory,Mallory          Mallory1,Mallory1        4
1   Seattle  Alice,Bob,Mallory,Bob  Alice1,Bob1,Mallory1,Bob1        5
```

Comment: Okay Thanks This is working, just one more thing suppose i have one more column with numbers and i have to calculate max or min with above operation for that column then how will i add two agg function in one statement.

Comment: Glad can help Good luck!

Comment: @vatsal you can also up-vote this answer and others to show additional appreciation.

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
In [42]: df1.groupby('City')['Name'].agg(','.join).reset_index(name='Name')
Out[42]:
       City                   Name
0  Portland        Mallory,Mallory
1   Seattle  Alice,Bob,Mallory,Bob
```

Or,

```
In [49]: df1.groupby('City', as_index=False).agg({'Name': ','.join})
Out[49]:
       City                   Name
0  Portland        Mallory,Mallory
1   Seattle  Alice,Bob,Mallory,Bob
```

For multiple aggregations

```
df1.groupby('City', as_index=False).agg(
      {'Name': ','.join, 'Name2': ','.join, 'Number': 'max'})
```

Comment: If i have one more column as Name2 then how will i use the above function to get the same results with string aggregation.

Comment: Check my answer.